Как проверить что все цифры в числе больше нуля?
Есть вопрос по задаче.
Условие:

Дано число, например, вот такое:
num = 12345

Проверьте, что все цифры этого числа больше нуля.

Попробовал написать код
n = int(input("Введите число: "))
flag = True
while n and flag:
     flag = n > 0
     n //= 10
print(flag)

Если ввести 12345, то выдаёт True.
А если ввести 120345 то выдаёт также True, хотя должен выдавать False.
Подскажите где ошибка.

Ошибка - в алгоритме.

Посмотрите чему равна n на каждой итерации

flag = n > 0 - тут вы проверяете не одну цифру числа, а остаточную часть числа

Можно сделать легкую команду:
def check(text:str='0123456789',symb:str='0'):
    return symb not in text

print(check('12305678', '0'))


если гарантируется, что в input точно число, то можно просто:
min(input()) != "0"


Каждую итерацию Вы только отсекаете от числа последнюю цифру. Но проверку для flag делаете по полностью оставшемуся числу, а не последнему отрезанному.
То есть у Вас проходят такие сравнения по flag = n > 0:
120345 > 0
12034 > 0
1203 > 0
120 > 0
12 > 0
1 > 0

Нужно каждую итерацию сравнивать с помощью n % 10 - остаток от деления на 10 даёт последнюю цифру. Тогда будет сравнивать так:
5 > 0
4 > 0
3 > 0
0 > 0 >>> False

Правильный вариант:
n = int(input("Введите число: "))
flag = True
while n and flag:
     flag = n % 10 > 0
     n //= 10
print(flag)


print(all(map(int, input ("введите число"))))

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map

В качестве забавной альтернативы предложу такое:
print('0' not in input("введите число"))


На вопрос уже дано довольно большое количество изящных ответов. Но в любом случае, вот простое решение в 33 строчки:
n = input()

n_int = int(n)

n_str = str(n_int)
flag = not False
for i in n_str:
    i_int = int(i)
    if i_int == 1:
        pass
    elif i_int == int(8.000):
        pass
    elif i_int == 6:
        pass
    elif i_int is 4:
        pass
    elif i_int == 2:
        pass
    elif i_int == 3:
        pass
    elif i_int == int('5'):
        pass
    elif i_int is 5+4:
        pass
    elif i_int == 7:
        pass
    elif i_int == 0:
        flag = True

if flag == True:
    print('Число без 0')
elif flag is not True:
    print('Число с 0')


Ужас какой. Ну это можно было ещё 100500 строк написать бесполезных. Строки вида elif условие: pass не делают ничего, их можно безболезненно выкинуть.

Про ужас согласен :)
А про бесполезность не совсем, каждая строчка приближает нас к поставленной задаче) хотя есть пара идей как сделать этот код ещё хуже, не добавляя ничего, что будет откровенно бесполезным

Dezmonder, вопрос.
У вас в коде при компиляции вот такое выдаёт:
Введите число: C:\Users\Яриор\PycharmProjects\Проверитьчто все цифры числа больше нуля\main.py:41: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
elif i_int is 5+4:

@YariorKorsaines я не уверен, зачем вы запускали этот код) SyntaxWarning, по сути не ошибка, это просто предупреждение, "не верно конструкция написана что". А подробности описаны в тексте: вместо "is" для чисел лучше использовать "==". Но при этом, код всё равно отработает корректно
